# How can I get an ActorRef of a Source?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-stream

Let's say I have a Source:

```
val source = Source(List(1,2,3))
```

How can I message the source like an actor?

```
sourceActor ! 4
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use simple collection-based source like that. You need another one like `Source.actorRef` or `Source.queue`. Keep in mind that using `Source.actorRef` does not give you backpressure and that messages send remotely over the network may get lost (due to at-most-once delivery semantic of actor communication).

Also, there's [an entire section](https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5.4/scala/stream/stream-integrations.html) in Akka documentation about integrating actors.

Comment: I haven't gave you a down vote. Also sorry, if you'll find my message insufficient, but I've assumed that you're familiar with how does akka.stream work. Every source needs to be materialized with some context - without it it's useless. When done that, it will return a materialized value, which is case of `Source.actorRef` is an `ActorRef` representation of that source.